# Reading a txt file using QTextStream C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a small program I have done before in Java however I want to try and get the same working in C++. The idea is to merge two text files

file1:

```
a
b
c
```

file2:

```
1
2
3
```

output file should read:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

I have looked at the QTextStream docs and this was the suggested code to read a file by line into strings

```
QFile file(input); // this is a name of a file text1.txt sent from main method
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    return 1;
}
QTextStream in(&file);
QString line = in.readLine();
while (!line.isNull())
{
    line = in.readLine();
}
```

Yet for some reason nothing is being loaded from the file at all. I proved this by printing 'line' to console and got nothing.

So any ideas? All I want is to read the file and end up with a string like this

```
QString text1 = "a\n2\n3"
```

I'd do this for both files, split the strings into QStringList (most likely) join them together in the format I want and write them to a 3rd txt file.

Comment: thanks to the grammar nazi for stopping by and not helping

Comment: yea i know @Roku thats basically what im asking, its not even reading the file because all 'input1' is, is 'text1.txt' no file path

Comment: Is there any specific reason it has to be QTextStream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you read line by line if you want the entire file?

```
QString line = in.readAll();
```

ALso, your while loop is wrong, you need to `while (!in.atEnd())` for the text stream instead of checking if the string is null.

`readLine` won't include the new line symbol.

Anyway, it would be much easier to open both files at the same time and construct your string on the go instead of splitting and joining.

```
QFile f1("h:/1.txt");
QFile f2("h:/2.txt");

f1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
f2.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

QString s;

QTextStream s1(&f1);
QTextStream s2(&f2);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    s.append(s1.readLine());
    s.append(s2.readLine());
    if (i != 2)s.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: cheers for the answer seems like exactly what i need however it still reads nothing, where do the txt files have to be to just be read by f1("text1.txt") cus i can basically put that in java and have it read from the project folder?

Comment: Well, it works for me, it doesn't really matter where the files are, I hard-coded it but it should work as long as you pass a valid path to the files. You don't get output probably because you are not opening the file properly. Does your method return 1?

Comment: no i mean im not putting in a file path im putting in a file name like you can in java (which then looks for that name in the project folder) im doing this because im getting the file names through user input from console, so does this work or am i actually going to have to specify a file path because that just seems stupid that theres no way to just specify a name

Comment: If you don't specify the full file path, file is being read from the current dir. That depends on how to run your application. And it hasn't anything to do with C++ or Java.

Comment: With the exception of the while loop your code looks OK, so the reason you are not getting output is `input` is not a valid file path and name. If the file is in your project folder, you only need the file name.

Comment: its ok i got it now, strangely enough apparently current dir wasnt the same folder as my project files were in ....

Answer (score 1):

If the file name does not contain full path, but you are very sure that the file is located in the same directory as your application, use the applications path like this:

```
QString filename = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this block-:

```
while(!in.atEnd())
{
   QString line = in.readLine();   
   ....
}
```

do you get output using this while loop?